# Denmark's capital in Russian?

Tags: перевод

I want to run this by you since sometimes the various language AI:s on internet comes back with various answers and I have seen different spelling variants in a few books depending on where the books are written.

Would Copenhagen be equivalent to: "Kопенгаген"?

Comment: Yes, "Kопенгаген", and I've never seen any other variants.

Comment: Wikipedia is good for such things: find article about a city, country, person, etc. in your favorite language and then follow link to Russian article (or any another language you need).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the one who's first language is Russian and who lives in Copenhagen, I can confirm that Копенгаген is correct. It is also common to name it Копен as short informal name in chat or small talk but not in email conversations.